# Akka Http Swagger setup - 406 application/octet-stream when referencing other file

Tags: scala, swagger, swagger-ui, akka-http

I'm trying to set up Swagger in a Scala project and running into issues referencing schemas in another file.

My folder structure for this is (the swagger folder has all the swagger-ui stuff):

- docs

  - swagger.yml
  - models

    - test_model.yaml
  - swagger

    - index.html
    - swagger-ui.css etc....

My swagger file references the index.html file and it loads fine.  All schemas that I define inside the swagger.yml file are loading and showing up correctly.  However, when I try to reference a file inside models such as test_model.yaml.  I get a 406 error on it loading the test_model.yaml file

```
Resource representation is only available with these types:
application/octet-stream
```

My akka set up for the routes for this is:

```
path("swagger") {
      getFromFile("docs/swagger/index.html") } ~
      getFromDirectory("docs/swagger") ~
      getFromDirectory("docs")
```

The first two seem to do what I expect.  My swagger ui page loads correctly and all of my routes/schemas defined in swagger.yml load fine.  However, when I use

```
$ref: './models/test_model.yaml#/components/schemas/Test'
```

It throws a 406 error when trying to load the test_model.yaml file.  The schemas are all defined correctly and if I keep them defined in the original swagger.yml file and reference them inside there it works fine.  It is only when I put them into an outside file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally got it working.  I had to add a custom ContentResolver for these routes to map the type for these files to `application/yaml` instead of the default resolver mapping them to Octet.